# how to fix buttons on the CSS box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The buttons are just not getting fixed on the CSS search-box. These Buttons should be on the search box but they are not getting fixed on the search-box and instead they have come out of the panel
I have tried using z-index but it did not work.

[image]

```js
$('#click').click(function()
{   
    $("#search-box").toggle();     
});
```

```css
   .panel{
 margin-top:60px;
 margin-left:30px;
 margin-right:30px;
 }
 
 .panel-heading{
 font-size:30px;
 text-align:center;
  
 }
 
 .table-box{
 margin-top:30px;
 }
 
 
   
  #search-box{
 height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    background:red;
    display: none;
    font-size: xx-large;

 }
 
  #seat{
 height: 20px;
    width: 40px;
    background:pink;
 
 }
```

```html
<! doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

 
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" >

<!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="custom_css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>  

   
<!---Font Awesome--->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 
 <!--font family-->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 

</head>  
  
<body>


<!--Table-->
<div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">Available Trips</p></div>
      <div class="panel-body">
          
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>  
      <tr>
        <th>Route Name</th>
        <th>Departure Time</th>
        <th>Arrival Time</th>
  <th>Available Seats</th>
  <th>Fare</th>
  <th>Search</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Banglore-Pune</td>
        <td>07:00 PM</td>
        <td>07:00 AM</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>Rs 1200</td>
  <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-success btn-block" id="click" value="Show/Hide"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>Search</button>

    <div id="search-box">
    <table>
  <tr>
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td></br>
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td> 
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td>
 <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td></br>
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td> 
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td></br>
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></div></td> 
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td>
 <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td></br>
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td> 
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td></br>
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td> 
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td>
 <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td></br>
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td> 
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td></br>
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td> 
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td>
 <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td></br>
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td> 
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>Book</button>


</div><!--search-box-->
</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Banglore-Pune</td>
        <td>09:00 PM</td>
        <td>07:00 AM</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>Rs 2000</td>
  <td> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-success btn-block" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>Search</button></td>

      </tr>
      
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--Table-->

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
     
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

<!--Custome Jquery-->
<script src="custom_js/main.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why is there 10 br tags before it??

Comment: Yeah, they are not needed. Thanks for bringing that to notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove those pointless `</br>` and `</div>` from the child table.

```js
$('#click').click(function()
{   
    $("#search-box").toggle();     
});
```

```css
   .panel{
 margin-top:60px;
 margin-left:30px;
 margin-right:30px;
 }
 
 .panel-heading{
 font-size:30px;
 text-align:center;
  
 }
 
 .table-box{
 margin-top:30px;
 }
 
 
   
  #search-box{
 height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    background:red;
    display: none;
    font-size: xx-large;

 }
 
  #seat{
 height: 20px;
    width: 40px;
    background:pink;
 
 }
```

```html
<! doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

 
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" >

<!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="custom_css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>  

   
<!---Font Awesome--->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 
 <!--font family-->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 

</head>  
  
<body>


<!--Table-->
<div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">Available Trips</p></div>
      <div class="panel-body">
          
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>  
      <tr>
        <th>Route Name</th>
        <th>Departure Time</th>
        <th>Arrival Time</th>
  <th>Available Seats</th>
  <th>Fare</th>
  <th>Search</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Banglore-Pune</td>
        <td>07:00 PM</td>
        <td>07:00 AM</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>Rs 1200</td>
  <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-success btn-block" id="click" value="Show/Hide"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>Search</button>

    <div id="search-box">
    <table>
  <tr>
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td>
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td> 
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td>
 <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td>
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td> 
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td>
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td> 
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td>
 <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td>
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td> 
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td>
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td> 
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td>
 <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td>
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td> 
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td>
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td> 
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td>
 <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td>
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td> 
    <td><button id="seat" style="margin:10px;"></button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>Book</button>


</div><!--search-box-->
</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Banglore-Pune</td>
        <td>09:00 PM</td>
        <td>07:00 AM</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>Rs 2000</td>
  <td> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-success btn-block" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>Search</button></td>

      </tr>
      
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--Table-->

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
     
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

<!--Custome Jquery-->
<script src="custom_js/main.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked I just did not notice them. Trying hard as a newbie.